# といいんです and といいんですけど

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles

What exactly is the difference between these two phrases. How does けど/が affect the meaning and how does it relate to its meaning of 'but'?

I asked a native speaker how to say "I hope I will be able to eat everything." (When presented with a very large meal). I was told 全て食べる事が出来るといいんですけど

Answer (score 1):

> ~といいですね

'I hope/wish X' (hope/wish for someone else)

> ~といいんですが
>
> ~といいんですけど

'I hope/wish X' (hope/wish for yourself)

---

- [E-Japanese: ～といい /～to ii /I hope, I wish.'](http://www.e-japanese.jp/?p=232)
- [gonihongo: Genki 2: Lesson 16 Grammar](http://www.gonihongo.com/genki2_grammar/16.html)

Answer (score 0):

The が・けど makes you sound more modest and tentative/hesitant.

Comment: I see, does it make it sound like you think the thing you hope might not happen?

Comment: You still want it to happen. But it shows that you aren't desperate and obsessed over it and modest and it would be great if it happened but I wouldn't cry over it.

Answer (score -3):

The difference between the two is the percentage of conviction in what you are saying.

Ending sentences with です usually indicates 100% of conviction.

On the other hand, sentences ending in といいんですけど would be lower than 100%.

Though the two phrases would mean the same thing, the nuance is slightly different.

Note: Sometimes ですけど can just be used as a conjunction while speaking, without any nuance of "but". It really depends on the entire context of the conversation.